# my mediatek mt7610u ubuntu 18.10 works badly

Tags: networking, wireless

I installed drivers for mt7610u(tp-link archer t1u v1) and i connected with 5 GHz wifi(200Mbit/s).
It reports that signal power is very low and when i do speedtest near modem, i have 30/35 Mbit/s. when I move away from the modem , signal is absent.
How can i solve?? i think it's a driver limitation due to the fact that driver is not official.

Comment: There is barely room for a wifi chip on that, it can't have much for an antenna

Comment: it's true, but i make same speedtest in windows 10 and it show max 120Mbit/s while in linux less than 60...